# SVG not drawing on safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, svg

Seems Safari is having some problems rendering my SVG, while other browsers does it correctly. Any idea on what is wrong?

Here is the URL:

http://bcndevcon.org/dev/infographic/

I've seen a lot of examples using iFrame, I don't know if it has something to do with the problem.

**Update: Seems server is sending the wrong content type, Content-Type: text/html**

[image]

**Update 2: In order to draw it correctly on all browsers use xhtml insted of html extension, for example: index.html**

Newbie error :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an XHTML page being served as `text/html`. Change your server to serve your page as `application/xhtml+xml`, or include the following as the first element in the `<head>`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
```

If Safari is interpreting your XHTML page as HTML, it will not interpret SVG elements as anything other than custom markup.

For reference, here is an example of [SVG in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml) that works in Safari, including using JavaScript to create SVG elements.

**Edit**: Additionally, you have *broken* XHTML; your `<link>` tag is missing a self-closing marker; see the [validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbcndevcon.org%2Fdev%2Finfographic%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

The real problem, however, is that you have a broken URI for your `<script>` element when referencing jQuery:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Throw a proper "http:" at the front of that URI and you will find your page working (if you fix the other two problems).

Comment: @Xavi See the edit. I have verified that with these fixes it works on Safari locally.

Comment: That isn't a broken URI in the script element. It's a perfectly valid "protocol-less" URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Comment: I validated the whole document, still not working on Safari Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1) and IE 8.0

Comment: @Xavi You have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in your head. You need an XHTML mime type, not an HTML mime type. Look again at the meta tag I supplied above.

Comment: @RoToRa Interesting, thanks for that. It is 'broken' when I'm testing locally via `file:` and the browser needs to fetch via `http:`, but of course that wouldn't be an issue for live deployment.

Comment: Sorry @Phrogz, I corrected that now and that's really weird, is not working yet, anyone else can see it in Safari OSX?

Comment: @Xavi Interesting. It does not work for me when I view it on your site, but if I save the XHTML file (and the CSS and JS files) locally, it loads fine for me in Safari over `file://`. My assumption then is that this is because your web server is still sending `Content-Type: text/html`.

Comment: @Phrogz, You are right. I checked it out with Charles Proxy and the content Type sent by the server is: Content-Type text/html

Comment: @Xavi Here is the final proof: http://phrogz.net/tmp/xavi_infographic.xhtml That file is sent with the proper mime type by the server and loads for me in Safari. Fix your server, and your problem will go away.

Comment: Holly **** :) Thanks @Phrogz, you really gave me the solution. I just had to change the index.html to index.xhtml. I'm sorry, I'm newbie on SVG

Comment: Now I just need to find the way to animate it. XD

Answer (score 2):

That's relying on `innerHTML` (via the [jQuery html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)) to parse html5 correctly, which probably isn't the case for the [version of Safari](http://caniuse.com/#svg-html5) you're using.

If you instead used DOM Core for creating the element's it would work just fine, or alternativly to use the [DOM Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) for parsing the svg fragments. See [this example](http://jsperf.com/svg-domparser-vs-createelement).