# Rendering through javascript

Tags: javascript, image, web, svg, render

I have been trying to render a svg image through javascript. Tried various options, but ultimately have to resolve to this one.

I have declared an object id in html like this

```
<object id="gauge1" type="image/svg+xml" data="gauge.svg" width="127" height="122"/>
```

Now, I have been trying to access this gauge.svg through javascript. I have created an element of embed type like this

```
this.m_svg = document.createElement('embed');
```

aand then trying to use `setAttribute` to access the image, but no success. Any suggestions?

Also pasting the svg code here with the image.

image: https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/179594_10150982737360698_1827200234_n.jpg
svg code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g name="gauge" width="122px" height="127px">
        <image xlink:href="gauging.png" width="122" height="127"/>
    <circle id="led" cx="39" cy="76" r="5" style="fill: #999; stroke: none">
        <animateColor id="ledAnimation" attributeName="fill" attributeType="css" begin="0s" dur="1s"
        values="none;#f88;#f00;#f88;none;" repeatCount="0"/>
    </circle>
        <g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)">
            <circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/>
            <rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/>
            <polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/>
        </g>
        <text id="value" x="51" y="98" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

PS : Already tried this.m_svg.innerHTML = svg code (Doesnt work on safari)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the content of the "embed" tag in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496241/how-to-access-the-content-of-the-embed-tag-in-html)

Comment: another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question. In that question, the image was loaded, and how to access the contents of the image was the question.

Comment: The first link again mention the second link. so thats not a duplicate either.

Comment: Not sure what you're after then, the answers to the other questions do cover accessing the svg content from <object>, <embed> and <iframe> in script.

Comment: I beg to differ on that. If you see it carefully, those questions have given the way to access elements of svg file, I, however, wants to set the image on the background using only javascript (with no reference to the svg file on html end)..

Comment: You have no reference to the svg? But the question says that you have it referenced with an <object> tag? Do you mean you have the svg as a javascript string that you want to parse and insert into the document? Or do you mean you have svg as a string that you want to use as a CSS background image for some element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-object.html) shows you how to access the elements that are the contents of an `<object>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your headers are set correctly, I know that webkit can get a little selective with it's SVG implementation unless headers are set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
```

for more info check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6410814/873836

Comment: ah, ok. Ive always had issues with SVG and generally just use Raphael these days to make it easier