# Can I use :// in place of http:// or https://?

Tags: http, https, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change all my  links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Is it possible to use just :// on all links during my development? For example, I would like to output

```
<select><option value="://my-page.html">Goto Page</option></select>
```

not

```
<select><option value="http://my-page.html">Goto Page</option></select>
```

or

```
<select><option value="https://my-page.html">Goto Page</option></select>
```

I have seen this somewhere before and was wondering if it is ok to do this as it would save a lot of time during development.

Also depending on what protocol the user comes in on, they would then be able to stay on that protocol throughout my website.

Comment: Michael, Thanks so much, that clarifies it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using `<option value` as your example. In this case, the browser will not recognize this as URL, so you would have to add the protocol (http/https) manually where you're using these values. `<option value` is just a text string from browser's point of view.

But you can achieve what you want for values the browser knows are URLs. For example:

```
<img src="/images/1.jpg" />
<script src="/js/jquery.js" />
```

By putting `/` in the beginning of the path, you tell the browser that the path is absolute, meaning that it starts from the root of your site.

Comment: Thanks Shedal, my mistake, it was meant to be <select><option value="://domain.com/my-page.html">Goto Page</option></select>, not just on selects but on all img's too

Comment: @Ian Is your intent to use these values in javascript? Like setting `document.location` to a path like this?

Comment: I have an issue with my https, its new ssl cert and if i navigate to my website using https i get warnings in ie saying that not all content is secure so i was hoping to just use :// to save me rewriting alot of my system and accomodating https:// within my scripts.