# Javascript for replacing an abreviation by his equivalent

Tags: javascript, text, replace, onkeypress

I met some trouble with a javascript.

In fact I have in my database many records that are abreviations and ther equivalent,

for example, replace tel => telephone etc...

So I have this function

```
$('#tags').keyup(function(e){
    var code = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
     console.log(code);
    if (code == 'tel'){
        var input = this.value;
        input = input.substr(0, input.length -1);
        console.log(input);
        input += 'tel';
        this.value = input;        
    }

});
```

Actualy this does not work the trouble is that I do not have aby mistakes
in the console of javascript.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

SP.

​

Comment: You can debug your javascript with tools like firebug

Comment: yes I use that but it did not display any mistakes

Comment: console.log(code) : shouldn't that give you keyCodes like 65 for 'a', etc ? It will not go inside the condition

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski I wasn't talking about displaying problems but about *debugging*. With firebug you can put breakpoints inside your code to see the values of each variable, and this can help you understand why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#tags').keyup(function(e){
    var code = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var input = this.value;
    if (input.indexOf('tel') != -1) {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/\btel\b/gi,'telephone');

    }

});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z3sP/1/)

Comment: This wil change only the literal "tel", not if it's enclosed in a string like "this is my tel"

Comment: dear sir, thanks for you reply I've done a php code that do a while for all words to be replaced. The trouble is that actualy it add a ? at the end of the script and this function do not work. I really do not know where does this ? comes from. Is there a way to remove that? Kind Regards.? SP

Comment: Are you referring to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988482/jsfiddle-code-not-working-on-local-machine/11988599#11988599

Comment: Oh thanks, This code works fine on the fiddle but not in my page, do I added this jQuery(function($){ and a } at the end, but it still does not work

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: `jQuery((function(){});` should work just fine, to ensure the `$` sign to work: `jQuery((function($){return function(){/* your code here*/};}(jQuery));` is what you're after. Mind you, this answer will change _visit Tel-Aviv_ to `visit telephone-Aviv`. I've updated my answer to a slightly more complicated but a lot more flexible sollution

Answer (score 3):

When using `keyup()` the event handler only returns the keycode of the pressed key. For instance an x results in e = 88.

Use `$("#tags").val()` to get the value of the input element.

Comment: so there is no way to replace a string on keypress?

Comment: Sure, there is, but the primary problem was that the code will never execute that command, as `code` will never be a string. Use `str.replace` for the replacement.

Comment: don't use `$('#tags')` in the handler, use either `$(this).val()`, `$(this)[0].value` or `this.value`. Using a jQuery selector will scan the DOM, which is slower and completely unnecessary, because you have a reference to the element: `this`

Answer (score 3):

the `keyCode` or `which` property doesn't return a string, or even a single char. It returns the *key code* that represents the key that was struck by the client. If you want to get the corresponding char: `String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);`.
If the user hit on the `a` key, for example, the keycode will be `97`, `String.fromCharCode(97)` returns `a`.

If you want to know weather or not the current value of the element contains the abreviation: `tel`, what you'll need to do is this:

```
$('#tags').keyup(function(e)
{
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\btel\b/gi,'telephone');
});
```

This is untested and *very likely* to need some more work, but AFAIK, you want to replace all occurrences of `tel` by `telephone`. The expression I use `/\btel\b/` replaces all substrings `tel`, provided they are preceded and followed by a word-boundary (to avoid replacing part of a word). 
Not that the end of a string and a dash are both considered to be word boundaries, too. If I wanted to type `television`, I'd end up typing `telephoneevision`. To avoid this, you'll need a slightly more complex expression. [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace/9514142#9514142) how you can avoid JS from treating a dash as a boundary, just work on it to take string-endings into account, too

*Update*

Perhaps this expression isn't quite as easy as I thought, so here's what I'd suggest you use:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/(?:(\-?\b))tel(?:(\b\-?.))/gi,function(all,b1,b2)
{
    if (b1 === '-' || b2.charAt(0) === '-')
    {//dash, don't replace
        return all;
    }//replace
    return b1 + 'telephone' + b2;
});
```

Input: *I need a tel, quickly* ==> *I need a telephone, quickly*
*I need a tel* ==> *I need a tel* (if the user is still typing, don't replace, he could be typing telescope, replace on submit or on blur)
*I want to book a hostel for tonight* ==> *I want to book a hostel for tonight*
*Visit Tel-Aviv* ==> *Visit Tel-Aviv*

Answer (score 1):

When using keypress this way the `code` variable will contain the **character code** of the pressed character. Not the string of chars like the expected 'tel'. You could use `onkeyup` / `onchange` event and check the val() of the input element and use `replace()` to change the abbreviation to the intended string.

```
$('#tags').keyup(function(e){

    var elem = $(this);
        var input = elem.val();

        // input = input.substr(0, input.length -1);  // This might not be necessary
        console.log(input);

        // do the replacement
        input = input.replace('tel','telephone');

        elem.val(input);        
    }

});
```

Comment: This will only replace the first occurance of `tel`, over and over again. If you type `tel and bell` the result will be something like `telephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephonetelephoneephone and bell`

Comment: I know this wil change every instance of "tel", so "hostel" will become  "hostelephone".. When using regex replace(/\stel\s|^tel\s|\stel$/i, 'telephone') this would be fixed.. ;) .. and I've just learned something ( the \b in regex ) myself thanks to Elias :)

Comment: I'd not use `tel$` in my expression, like I said in my answer: client won't be able to type `I want to by a television` because, at some point, the input will be `I want to by a tel` --> matches `\stel$` and will be replaced

Answer (score 0):

Use [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method for replacing a word in string.

eg:

```
var str = "This is AIR";
var newstr = str.replace("AIR", "All India Radio");
console.log(newstr);
```