# Calling Javascript in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

how to I call the following javascript in c# linkbutton_click event.
This following code is on the aspx page and I want to call this from the codebehind

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintPanel() {
        var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=1000,width=900');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.print();

        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't.  JavaScript is client-side, C# is server-side.  The two can't directly reference each other.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes you can. Use ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock or RegisterAtstartup. Not directly but you can.

Comment: @David I got this working fine onClientclick yet, this only works on my local pc and not the server side

Comment: @user3012159: What's the difference between those two environments?  When this is running from the server, in what way does it fail?

Comment: I dont get any errors from the server. it just dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `linkbutton_click`

```
Type myType = this.GetType();
//You may not need this if statement
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(someType, "_linkbutton_click"))
{
    string script = "PrintPanel;";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(someType, "_linkbutton_click", script, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function on `OnClientClick` of the linkbutton.

Add `OnClientClick="return PrintPanel();"` to your `LinkButton`.

Comment: Yes, this works fine on my local pc and not server ? any clues as to why ?

Comment: use `single-quotes` for `getElementById` as `document.getElementById('<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>');`

Comment: for `pnlContents` control add `ClientIDMode="Static"` and use just "pnlContents" as `document.getElementById("pnlContents")`

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309903/why-is-my-javascript-not-working-locally-or-on-server-but-working-on-jsfiddle