# PHP include with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I haven't found anything, so hopefully I can get an answer here?

I'm seeing the following error when loading content on a php page of mine:

> TypeError: $(...).load is not a function [Break On This Error]
>
> $(document).load(function() {

So I took a look at my current jQuery settings, including source in Firebug, and confirmed the following:

- jQuery 1.8.0 is loaded correctly
- I've added conditional statement before load call to check if jQuery is populated.
- Library that I am using has loaded
- alerts before the document load are firing

Here is my code - Is there something not allowed with PHP include files and jQuery?:

```
<html>
<head> ...... </head>
<body>
    <div id='header'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                animSpeed: 500,
                pauseTime: 5000,
                slices:40
            });
        });

    </script>

    <!-- Included file -->
    <div id='container'>
        <div style="height:245px;" id="wrapper">
                <div style="height:245px;" class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                    <div style="height:245px;" class="nivoSlider" id="slider">
                        <img data-transition="sliceUpDownLeft" alt="" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" src="images/toystory.jpg">
                        <img title="This is an example of a caption" data-transition="sliceUpDownLeft" alt="" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" src="images/up.jpg">
                        <img data-transition="sliceUpDownLeft" alt="" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" src="images/walle.jpg">
                        <img title="#htmlcaption" data-transition="sliceUpDownLeft" alt="" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" src="images/nemo.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nivo-html-caption" id="htmlcaption">
                        <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. 
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End included file -->

    <div id='footer'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to reflect your statements, where is for example the conditional statement you are talking about?

Comment: This is a PHP question without PHP code whatsoever. Where is the PHP in this?

Comment: error shows `$(document).load(function(){` when you are using `$(window).load` ?  Or is that a typo

Comment: @user82302124 change your jquery inclusion src to h t t p://ajax... See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't care what goes on clientside - the code that runs on the browser (JavaScript) and your server (PHP) do not interact at all, *even when PHP generates a page containing JavaScript.*

The **only** time they intersect is indirectly, when you use PHP to pre-populate JavaScript constants (usually a bad idea) or when the JavaScript uses GET/POST to send data back to a new instance of the script (standard practice.)

So with that discounted, let's look at your page in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rfh9A/

It works fine there, though I had to point the NivoSlider link at GitHub. So now we have only a few options:

1. Your actual code is different from what you posted
2. You're loading this page via AJAX and jQuery is already part of the parent document. This has caused issues for me in the past, particularly when you're loading two different versions of the library. It might work if you change `$` to `jQuery`, in case the library's disabled the shorthand for compatibility.
3. A JavaScript error in a part of the page not pasted (see answer 1) is preventing jQuery from instantiating.
4. (Long shot) You've got a DNS problem or something on your local machine preventing the jQuery library from loading on your browser.

Comment: I tried your http://jsfiddle.net/Rfh9A/,as a local html file. it seems chrome is treating the //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js include as being a local file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Comment: That shouldn't impact his document or my suggestion - this is, in fact, the way Google recommends incorporating their CDN's offerings, so it's (generally speaking) likely to work.

Comment: He's very likely using the html as a local file(without a server) See Dave Ward's answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Comment: He's loading it through PHP, which means it's coming through a server. Even if it's local, he isn't using the `file` protocol so that's not relevant. From the answer you linked: "Using a local web server like Apache or IIS to test against http://localhost addresses works fine though."

Comment: This is correct. I had an JS error that was causing this not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Edit:

Disregard what I said.

If you are using this in a local html file the jquery inclusion with the // path will be treated as a local file such as `file:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js`, which doesn't exist.

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He's using weird methods to call it, for sure, but the pasted code works fine with only the nivoslider path altered.

Comment: He's also probably using .load because he wants the images to have loaded before the slider starts sliding

Comment: @KerrM, @ sudowned, yup you are both right.

Answer (score -1):

Try including your javascript files within the `<head></head>` tags to ensure it's all loaded before your inline script runs.

Comment: I've tried this as well, just to make sure. No luck.