# Dijit first tutorial

Tags: javascript, dojo

I know this shall be a very silly question but some years have passed since the last time I developed some javascript. 
I'd like to brush on that and so I decided to learn some Dojo. 
The problem is that I can't manage to get this simple Dijit example working
As far far as I understand it should produce a button with a Click Me label but the only thing I get is an empty button. It seems the script is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Dijit</title>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <button id="btn"></button>
        <script>
        require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button) {
            var button = new Button({
                label: "Click Me!",
                onClick: function(){ console.log("First button was clicked!"); }
            }, "btn");
            button.startup();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works fine for me (in FF, not IE :/) http://jsfiddle.net/Xahhk/

Comment: Do you run it on localhost or in some jsFiddle/JSBin? I'm asking because I tested it in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/omokok/2/edit) and it does not work there on the 1st load after the page refresh or when the cache is disabled, but it works correctly (even w/ cache disabled) in the latest Chrome, Firefox and Opera, and also in IE9, IE8, IE7 and IE6, when served via my local Apache.

Comment: I tried it on localhost with FF/IE/Chrome :(

Comment: Works for me too.  Don't see any reason why this would not work.  I'd try all the usual Javascript debugging stuff, stick a few console.log() lines in it to see where it gets to in the script before breaking.  Check that the dojo loader is actually being loaded (perhaps it is being blocked on your network...etc).  Also, copy'n'past your code posted here into a test page to ensure they are both the same (ie. code here works for us but your local one does not work - hence, might be different).  All obvious stuff, lost count of the time my code was broken because of something silly.

Comment: I've also try turning off the parseOnLoad option and running a manual parse, ie. using dojo/ready + dojo/parser - see: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/declarative/ - Instantiating Objects section

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the page using a file:// URL (or double-clicking the file), it won't work due to the schema-less URI's you're using to load the stylesheet and dojo.

Try adding the protocol "http" before the leading pair of slashes in the respective link & script tags.

See also [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)