# jquery.min.js Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, debugging

Why this link doesn`t work?

**//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="Description" content=" [wstaw tu opis strony] ">
    <meta name="Keywords" content=" [wstaw tu slowa kluczowe] ">
    <meta name="Author" content=" [dane autora] ">
    <title>[tytuł strony] </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".animat_kon").click(function () {
                $(".animat_text").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

error example:
[image]

Comment: Is your html page sitting on a frame? Is it located on an HTTP or HTTPs port? If it's on a frame it wont let you load cross domain scripts.

Comment: @FedericoGiust You can load scripts from a different origin. That's why we have JSONP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you did not included http://

whenever you are downloading from the server directly then use`http://`

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

into

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You missed the `http:`. You can skip the `http:` to let your browser automatically choose between HTTPS and HTTP. But in your case the debugging tool seems not to understand this syntax.

Find more information here: [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Answer (score 3):

The link must start with `http://`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your script src to:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

script src should start with ***`http://`***