# Why won't jquery run on my local machine?

Tags: jquery

The following script will work on jsfiddle (see below) but wont work on my local machine.

http://jsfiddle.net/gFaZn/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

<div></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: For an explanation, see [this answer from Dave Ward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just#answer-4832046)

Answer (score 4):

`//` tells the browser to match the current protocol. It's fine if you're on a webserver, as it'll switch to `http` or `https`, but you're probably loading the file directly with the browser, so it'll expand to `file://`.

You need to specify the protocol explicitly:

```
src="http://...
```

Better yet, use a local webserver.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Will not be understand running locally. add `http://` and try agian.
And just for your information, JQuery is just javascript and always runs in your browser. So if something doesnt work while using javascript it is or a programming error or a wrong link to JQuery file. Either way, it wont be javascript it self.

Comment: Cheers Patrick, I thought that might be the case. I tried both with and without the http:// The other link seemed to sort the issue though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

your source url doesnt link to anything your machine can see perhaps?

a quick test might be

```
$(function(){
  alert(9);
});
```

if you dont see the alert then jQuery is not loaded.  Fully qualify the path