# Can mail clients handle URLs starting with // instead of http://?

Tags: http, email, url, https

Most web browsers can handle URLs that start with "//" instead of "http://" or "https://" but what about the most common mail clients like Outlook and Thunderbird, or even Gmail?

**Update:**
Found a good answer here...
[Is it safe to use protocol relative URL in email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869320/is-it-safe-to-use-protocol-relative-url-in-email)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use protocol relative URL in email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869320/is-it-safe-to-use-protocol-relative-url-in-email)

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, wouldn't clients like Gmail be able to handle/support this? Due to the fact you're opening up gmail in a browser that currently already supports doing that.

After sending a test e-mail to myself, I found that using the "//" worked fine too, however I wouldn't be able to say otherwise for Thunderbird as I've never used it.