# Why is "http:" missing when including a .js file from a CDN?

Tags: javascript, cdn

Today I came across this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Which I think should be this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can someone explain why all the CDN folks omit the `http:` in their include snippets? CloudFlare does it too:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js
```

But why? Does even the dumbest browser get this or is it safer to just add `http:`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Answer (score 3):

Look http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt for "relative reference". The path referenced is relative to used scheme. So, if your website is http://www.example.com the `http`-part is the scheme. Now in "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" the `//` part signals, that you want to go *relative* to the scheme of your site, meaning in this case relative to `http`.

Comment: Please , avoid **reference-only** answers. Some comment about the link will be appreciated.