# How to load javascript libraries securely

Tags: javascript, https

I apologize if this question is simplistic, beginning web developer here.

I have a page that I am serving securely as https. The page uses the following two libraries:

```
<script src="http://myjs.us/param.js"></script>
<script src="http://myjs.us/entify.js"></script>
```

I am getting errors of the following type:

> [blocked] The page at ... was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure
>   content from 'http://myjs.us/param.js': this content should also be
>   loaded over HTTPS.

So I get why I am getting this error, it is because I am loading the javascript libraries from an unsecure source. My question is where can I get these from a secure source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They seem to be rather small files. Can you not copy and paste them into your scripts directly?

Comment: You are getting this error since you are loading your js using the http protocol, `http://myjs.us`. You need to change this to https

Comment: Remove the protocol from the URL. use `src="//myjs.us/param.js"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [... this content should also be loaded over HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196927/this-content-should-also-be-loaded-over-https)

Answer (score 2):

The basic solution is to remove the protocol form the URL when you call the javascript, change

```
<script src="http://myjs.us/param.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script src="//myjs.us/param.js"></script>
```

With this you ensure that the javascript will load with the same protocol of the entire page.

Be sure that the server supports `https` (myjs.us for you), otherwise you will get an error like *failed to load resource...*, In  this case, maybe you want to use a CDN with `https` support, like [**cdnjs**](https://cdnjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the protocol in your URLs:

```
<script src="//myjs.us/param.js"></script>
<script src="//myjs.us/entify.js"></script>
```

The browser will default to the current protocol being used by the page, in this case `https`.  Of course, if `myjs.us` doesn't support `https` then that would be another issue entirely, and one you can't really solve from your page.

Comment: yeah, now I am getting: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: @bob: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response

Comment: I didn't see this answer. @bob: take a look to my answer (the cdn part at the end)