# IE9 fail to load CSS over SSL

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, ssl

Recently, we noticed that CSS fails to load on IE9 over SSL, is there a way to fix this issue? We're using asp.net and IIS. Is there some setting that needs to be done to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because mixing http and https content in the same page can sometimes be a security risk.

To fix it, either specify that the css always be https, or (better) use [Schema-less URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2). A schema-less url simply omits the "http:" or "https:" part of the address. Instead of something like "`http://www.example.com/style.css`", you do this: "`//www.example.com/style.css`".

**[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)**