# How to access protocol-less URL like "//xxx.js" when double-click a local html file in browser

Tags: javascript, html, http, url, https

I am writing a `html` file in which it needs to visit a third-party `js` file. The `js` file would access other resources using the **protocol-less URLs**, such as: `<img src="//xxx/xx.png..>`. When I upload the html and access the page through the website, the resources could be successfully visited. And the local webserver `localhost://` works fine too.

However, if I double-click the `html` file and open it with a browser directly, these resources could not be accessed. I checked with `Inspect Element` and found the scheme was `file://`, and the URL of the resource that third-party 'js' file try to access turns to be something like: `file://xxx/xx.png`, which of course couldn't be found.

Since I couldn't modify the third-party `js` file, so my questions are:

- Is where any way to specify the scheme manually?
- Or how could I make the resources accessible in this condition?

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just#answer-4832046), it indicates that this might be the drawbacks for **protocol-less URL**. But I am wondering since the scheme could be detected and set in the URL, it might be possible to set it directly.

Comment: You could always just use `<img src="http://xxx/xx.png..>` but then it won't be protocol-less.

Comment: @Denocle the statement is written in the third-party file, I couldn't modify it.

Comment: Run your webpages from a webserver instead of local files.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for the information, I know it could work if I run it from a webserver. I want to know whether it would also work when running it as a local file.

Comment: If you can not manipulate the URL, then no, there is no way to get it work – it is called a protocol-_relative_ URL for a reason.

Comment: A super hacky way of solving this would be to copy the third party JavaScript and change it to how you want it, OR write your own JavaScript to change the specific parts, of the third party script, to your needs.

Comment: @Denocle, thanks, i could have a try.