# Adding a Facebook like button to my markup using iframe document not working

Tags: javascript, html, fbml, xfbml

I tried  my possible best to make it work but I couldn't.

This is what I did.

1. follow the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
2. copy and paste my iframe tag to my test.html file inside the `<body>`.
3. horiyang is the name of the facebook.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <body>
   <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fhoriyahng%2F&amp;width=200x200&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200x200px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Could you please add the code that you have in your test.html page in your question?

Comment: Are you loading the test page from file://? If so, try loading the page from a server.

Comment: i uploaded it,you can check

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please add **https:** before // in your `iframe` tag 
like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fhoriyahng%2F&amp;width=200&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This is fiddle link where your box is working check it.   http://jsfiddle.net/u5Lgeg5e/

Comment: No, that is [correct syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831741/505649) to keep the protocol of the initial page.

Comment: See your width element value ... This is also showing wrong value ... Check this