# What are the rules on URLs written without the protocol?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I don't remember when I started seeing URLs without the protocols.

```
<script src="//jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

... but I immediately understood. It's great not to have to list the protocol when we don't know what it will be. Unfortunately I don't know what the rules are here.

Is this okay too?

```
<link href="//stylesheet.com/stylesheet.css" />
```

What about this?

```
/* stylesheet.css */
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
```

I'm not just looking for the answers here, but where to look to read the definitive guide. And I don't even know what this technique is called.

I don't know what the browser support is or what would happen in a case where the browser didn't support it.

Thanks for the help!

**Update**

A lot of the answers I was looking for are found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4831741/2535178).

Comment: Just as you can write `/path/from/root.css`, you can write `//example.com/url/relative/to/protocol`. It's just a relative link.

Comment: "scheme-less URL" is the keyword you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just Not sure there is a definitive guide anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

These are called protocol-relative URIs.

The resolution rules are described in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

> ## 4.2.  Relative Reference
>
> A relative reference takes advantage of the hierarchical syntax
>     (Section 1.2.3) to express a URI reference relative to the name space
>     of another hierarchical URI.
>
> ```
>   relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
>                 / path-absolute
>                 / path-noscheme
>                 / path-empty
> ```

Section 5.4 has examples.

> ## 5.4.  Reference Resolution Examples
>
> Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
>
> ```
>   http://a/b/c/d;p?q
> ```
>
> a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows.
>
> ```
>   ...
>   "//g"           =  "http://g"
>   ...
> ```