# Why is Font-Awesome not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm linking font-awesome in my html file like this:  `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head>`

The icons are not showing up when I'm working locally on my website.
But they are showing up on the server!

1. I thought it could be the extension Ad Plus which is blocking it, but it's not because even if I test it on a browser that doesn't have this extension, it also doesn't work. Moreover, it works fine on the server with Ad Plus.
2. Then I thought it could be XAMPP and I might not have my Apache server on. But everything is running fine!
3. I also checked the link inside the `<head>` and changed it to previous versions, but that didn't make any difference (still not working locally).
4. I've read everything I could find on SO and google about this problem, but am lost to as why it's not working locally.

I've even made a fiddle to double check wether it works correct online and it does: http://fiddle.jshell.net/g1qor20y/ 
In the fiddle I copied everything from my `<head>` since I thought the problem could be found there, but it works fine online.

Why is it not working locally? It's not showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource doesn't specify a protocol. Protocol-less links break on `file://`.

Specify `http://`... when working locally. If you never use `https://`, feel free to always use `http://` in your resource links.

Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832046/1234256

Comment: Thank you very much! 
It worked out great :)
It's one of those things I won't be forgetting soon.

Answer (score 2):

using // is great when you want code to work both with http:// as well as https:// - but locally, the browser will then look for file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css - assuming it is on your machine..