# some CSS can not show when swith the website from http to https

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, https

I have a website written in Ruby using Ruby on Rail framwork, everything was fine when using HTTP protocol, but when switching to HTTPS protocol.

**Some CSS material can not shown, but some of it can.**

The font can not be shown, originally the font was designed, but now it is not.

Anyone know what happen?

Answer (score 0):

Without any specific error I assume browser is probably blocking files loading from mixed content, i.e. using both HTTP and HTTPS. Use your browser developer tools network tab to confirm this.

You can use `//` instead of `http://` so that resources load from the relative protocol that the page content is loading from; [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Also read; [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)