# javascript loading - why test for protocol?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that the script Twitter uses to load widget.js on your page detects for the protocol and not use [Protocol-relatiave URL](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/)

```
var p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
js.src = p + '://www.twitter.com/widget.js';
```

instead of

```
js.src = '//www.twitter.com/widget.js';
```

Is there any reason why you should do that?  Maybe backwards compatibility?

Comment: Related: [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831741/464709)

Comment: Thanks.  I think this answers my question.