# sharePoint 365 Iframe issue

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have an issue with Office 365 HTML page , when I add any js file from another CDN or external URL it will not work, even adding Ifram it's not working.

here is a sample of that code :

```
 <!-- INSTANSIVE WIDGET -->
                    <script src="assets/js/instansive.js"></script>
                    <iframe src="//instansive.com/widgets/cdf503d7211fb7e7034b029afb67aacf75c3087b.html" id="instansive_cdf503d721" name="instansive_cdf503d721" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="instansive-widget" style="width: 100%; border: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Please if any solution let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason your iframe is not working is because you are missing the http: in the source path.

Change:
src="//instansive.com/widgets/cdf503d7211fb7e7034b029afb67aacf75c3087b.html"

Change to:
src="http://instansive.com/widgets/cdf503d7211fb7e7034b029afb67aacf75c3087b.html"

I tested the change and it works correctly on my machine (Macbook Air) using chrome.

Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Protocol-relative URLs are supposed to work in `iframe` though, e.g. see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/mbLGfOfTVRc

Comment: It may be the instansive widget itslef that is not handling the protocol-relative properly. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just