# MVC Url.Action and Routing Configuration Relation

Tags: url, model-view-controller, url.action

I would like to revise the questions here, my focus is on MVC Url.Action:

I am testing on `Url.Action` in view `http:// localhost:22334/Order/Index`

@Url.Action("Summary", "Order")

When the route config is

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Order",
            url: "{lang}/Order/{action}",
            defaults: new { lang = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Order", action = "Index" }
        );

  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{*pathInfo}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Order", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It generate a link `//Order/Summary` which is not working

However when the Route Config is added with constrait

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Order",
            url: "{lang}/Order/{action}",
            defaults: new { lang = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Order", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { lang = "[a-z]{2}" }
        );

  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{*pathInfo}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Order", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It generate a link `/Order/Summary` which works well

1. Is URL.Action depends on the routing?
2. Since I am testing on localhost, will URL.Action generate different result when I put on server like 'http://myserver/myapps/ordersystem/Order/Index

Thanks

Best Regards,

mintssoul

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Comment: There is a fair discussion on the effects of leaving the protocol off that is linked to when I flagged your question as a duplicate.