# reference to CSS residing on third party server

Tags: css

when I give reference of CSS on third party server using `http://<link to CSS>` it perfectly loads the CSS.

But When I give reference using `//<link to CSS>` the CSS doen't load.

Tested this in chrome and firefox.
Is there any specific reason behind CSS not working with `//<link>` ?

Comment: It sounds like a possible CORS issue, with them not allowing their content to be loaded over HTTPS. If it works over regular HTTP, I'd stick with that :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge - insecure content on a secure webpage is an security issue, and nobody should be making non-HTTPS sites in 2017

Comment: For an external reference to CSS? I've yet to hear of a security vulnerability through loading CSS over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use protocol relative urls?

If your document is on http and you are loading js in https then it wont be any issue. And if the document is https and your trying to load http then it can cause problem. May be some browsers blocked content. If your js is available on https then always use https.

Also read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)