# Facebook Like Button Popup doesn't load

Tags: facebook, plugins, cross-domain, facebook-like

This is my first question *asked*, so if I leave out details please be a little lenient. Thanks!

I am using the Facebook Like Button plugin on my site (tried both HTML5 version and xfbml version). I have included all necessary tags and scripts for xfbml and HTML5 support. I have followed the "spec" and done a thorough amount of searching here and elsewhere to the problem:

The like button functions correctly, except that the flyout/popup that is supposed to show after clicking the button doesn't load. I mean **load**, not **show** (and yes I already checked for `overflow:hidden` issues per the [spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)). The new `<span>` (which includes the `<iframe>`) are added to the DOM immediately after the like button `<span>`, and they load all of the code that is supposed to be there:

```
<span class=" fb_edge_comment_widget fb_iframe_widget " style="top: 19px; left: 0px; z-index: 10000;">
  <span>
    <iframe id="fa02aa64d8da" class="fb_ltr" scrolling="no" name="fee6eb9f6f2768" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 225px; width: 401px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_widget_shell.php?api_key=233493930007947&locale=en_US&master_frame_name=fa12240bc73214&sdk=joey">
      <html>
        <head>
        <body onload="onPageLoad()">
          <script>
            var onPageLoad = function() {
              document.domain = 'facebook.com';
              var loc = window.location.toString();
              var index = loc.indexOf('?');
              var qs = loc.substring(index + 1);
              var params = qs.split('&');
              var master_frame_name = '';
              for (var i in params) {
                var components = params[i].split('=');
                if (components[0] == 'master_frame_name') {
                  master_frame_name = components[1];
                  break;
                }
              }
              try {
                var master_frame = parent.frames[master_frame_name];
                master_frame.ExternalNodeConnectWidget.onCommentWidgetLoaded(document);
              } catch (e) {}
            };
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </span>
</span>
```

Now after that `<span>` is loaded it is supposed to fire the script function `onPageLoad` which should **load** all of the data into the `<iframe>`. Instead I get a bunch of errors:

1. There is the infamous [Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577947/facebook-gives-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-error-in-chr)
2. When you manually run the onPageLoad() function (in hopes of it loading the content into the iframe) in the console/Firebug, you get

(in Chrome 15)

```
    Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
      code: 18
      message: "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"
      name: "SECURITY_ERR"
      __proto__: DOMException
```

(in Firefox 7)

```
    Error: Illegal document.domain value
    document.domain = 'facebook.com';
```

I presume this has to do with cross-domain requests, but it seems like for other people, they just get the error but the popup still loads properly. **Any ideas how to get this to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known Facebook bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293075054049400

Basically, one gets this behavior if secure browsing is enabled on the Facebook user's account.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it was reported a couple weeks after I asked it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have secure browsing disabled (as it is default) here is another possible solution:
You cannot use localhost in the og:url since Facebook cannot surf that page to get the data. So when developing, enter the live site URL in og:url, og:image, the like/share button url etc. Even that might not help, the click needs to be made on the live site, when I deployed it worked fine.

Anyone know a work around for this to make it easier when developing locally?

Comment: Generally I get most of the Facebook functionality to work when developing locally by adding `http://localhost/` to the "mobile web URL" section of your FB developers app interface. This allows you to use a completely different domain from your normal domain and still have it function.